# $\text{int}(\text{cl}\,A) \subset A$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, and $A\in\mathcal{T}$.

I'm trying to prove that the interior of the boundary of an open set $A$ is empty.

Note: We define the boundary of $A$ as $\partial A = (\text{cl}\,A) \setminus \text{int}A$

What I've tried is:

$$\text{int}(\partial A) = \text{int}(\text{cl}\,A \setminus\text{int}\,A) = \text{int}(\text{cl}\, A) \setminus A \quad(A \text{ is an open set} \Rightarrow \text{int}\,A = A)$$

Now my question is: $\text{int}(\text{cl}\,A) \subset A$ ? If that's true then $\text{int}(\partial A) = \text{int}(\text{cl}\, A) \setminus A \subset A\setminus A = \varnothing$ and that's it.

If not, how can I approach this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670944/interior-of-the-boundary-of-an-open-set-is-empty

Comment: And of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142892/prove-that-the-interior-of-the-boundary-is-empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that $int(cl(A))\subset A$ (even if $A$ is open) as the example $A=\mathbb R-\{0\}\subset \mathbb R$ shows. The interior of the closure is everything.

As for the overarching question: Let $B:=int(\partial A)$. Put $C:=B\cap A$. Note that $C$ is open (as intersection of two opens) and $C\subset A$ (by construction), hence $C\subset int(A)$. This means $C= C\cap int(A) = B\cap A\cap int(A)=B\cap int(A)=\emptyset$ (where the last equality holds because $B\subset \partial A$). Hence $B\cap A=\emptyset$. But this means that $cl(A)-B$ is a closed set (since $B$ is open) which contains $A$; this can only happen if $B$ is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Tashi ! Just one more question: 

At the end when you say "this can only happen if B is empty" is it because if that's not true it contradicts the fact that the closure is the smallest closed set containing A?

Comment: @F.A. That's exactly right. By definition, the closure of $A$ is the smallest closed set which contains $A$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, your approach does not work. Try arguing by contradiction. Assume $x\in int(\partial A)$. Then $x$ has some neighborhood $U$ contained in $\partial A$. Since $x$ is a boundary point of $A$, there is some other point $y\in U$ such that $y\in A$. Now derive a contradiction using $y$.

Comment: In that case we have $y \in A$ and $y \in U \subset \partial A$, but that's a contradiction with $A$ being an open set. Is this correct? @juan